# Query complexity of exact learning and combinatorial parameter

Tags: lower-bounds, learning-theory

When defining the query complexity of exact learning for a concept $c$ (considered as a function from $\{0,1\}^n \mapsto \{0,1\}$) in a concept class $\mathcal{C}$, we often come across the following definitions leading to query complexity theorems (see R.Servedio and S.Gortler, *Equivalences and Separations between Quantum and Classical Learnabbility* for instance).

Let $\mathcal{C'} \in \mathcal{C}$. For $a \in \{0,1\}^n$ and $b \in \{0,1\}$, let $\mathcal{C'}_{<a,b>} = \{ c \in \mathcal{C'} : c(a) = b \}$. Then define:
$$\gamma^{\mathcal{C'}}_{<a,b>} = \frac{\lvert \mathcal{C'}_{<a,b>} \rvert}{\lvert \mathcal{C'} \rvert}$$
$$ \gamma^{\mathcal{C'}}_a = min(\gamma^{\mathcal{C'}}_{<a,0>},\gamma^{\mathcal{C'}}_{<a,1>})$$
$$ \gamma^{\mathcal{C'}} = max\{ \gamma^{\mathcal{C'}}_a : a \in \{0,1\}^n \} $$
And finally let:
$$ \hat{\gamma}^{\mathcal{C}} = \underset{\mathcal{C'} \subseteq \mathcal{C}, \lvert \mathcal{C'} \rvert \geq 2}{min} \gamma^{\mathcal{C'}} $$
i.e. :
$$ \hat{\gamma}^{\mathcal{C}} = \underset{\mathcal{C'} \subseteq \mathcal{C}, \lvert \mathcal{C'} \rvert \geq 2}{min} \ \ \ \underset{a \in \{0,1\}^n}{max} \ \ \ \ \underset{b \in \{0,1\}}{min} \frac{\lvert \mathcal{C'}_{<a,b>} \rvert}{\lvert \mathcal{C'} \rvert}$$

I'm not sure to totally understand why using these definitions. Say we want to learn $c \in \mathcal{C}$. If we identify an $a$ such that $c(a) = 0$ whereas for most of $\tilde{c} \in \mathcal{C}$ , $ \tilde{c}(a) = 1$ then it's great for the learning algorithm because we can discard a lot of concepts that does not match $\tilde{c}(a) = 1$. However these above definitions have an inner min ($min$ on $b \in \{0,1\}$) which would give us a poor bound on the number of concepts we can discard in the case I mention in the paragraph.

Is this because we have to give a query bound independent of which concept we want to learn in the class? And thus we cannot use the membership query for a specific concept. I still think it would not be equivalent to specifying a concept and taking the maximum query complexity (which is what I would have done intuitively).